# Convert Raw Query to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need MySQL raw query to Laravel.

```sql
select * from `mh_sms_authorchecklist` as `a` 
inner join `mh_sms_selectedrevlist` as `s` on `a`.`orderNumber` = `s`.`orderNumber` 
where `a`.`manuscriptStatus` = '24'
and `a`.`submitStatus` = '1' 
and ( select count( 1 ) 
     FROM mh_sms_selectedrevlist as s
        WHERE s.OrderNumber = a.OrderNumber AND   s.editorType =  'Editor' 
        AND  s.editorID =  '516' AND s.scoreSubmit = '1') = 1;
```

I have tried like the following but somehow it does not work for me

```php
DB::table("mh_sms_authorchecklist as a") 
    ->join('mh_sms_selectedrevlist as s', 'a.orderNumber', '=', 's.orderNumber')
    ->where("a.manuscriptStatus", '24')
    ->where("a.submitStatus",  '1')
    ->where(DB::raw("( select count( 1 ) FROM mh_sms_selectedrevlist as s
        WHERE s.OrderNumber = a.OrderNumber AND   s.editorType =  'Editor' 
        AND  s.editorID =  '516' AND s.scoreSubmit = '1') = 1 "))
    ->get();
```

Comment: To try out what is going to run, instead of using `->get()` write `->toSql()` and compare it

Comment: Yes I have try ->toSql, it returns me the same query without bindings, when I put values and run it in mysql, it returns me the records Okay

Comment: But somehow in Laravel it does not return me the records, I dont know why

Comment: If it is the same query, then you do not have data or something like that, maybe the bindings are not correctly set, so there you have a mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track in converting the raw query to Laravel's query builder. However, there was a slight hiccup. In the original code, you tried to use a raw SQL expression **within** the `where()` method, but this method doesn't really interpret raw SQL expressions correctly.

All you gotta do is use Laravel's `whereRaw()` method instead of `where()`. The `whereRaw()` method is specifically meant for handling raw SQL expressions, which is exactly what you need for your subquery.

[Laravel - whereRaw / orWhereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)

Here's an example:

```
$result = DB::table("mh_sms_authorchecklist as a")
            ->join("mh_sms_selectedrevlist as s", "a.orderNumber", "=", "s.orderNumber")
            ->where("a.manuscriptStatus", '24')
            ->where("a.submitStatus", '1')
            ->whereRaw("(select count(1) from mh_sms_selectedrevlist as s
                         where s.OrderNumber = a.OrderNumber and s.editorType = 'Editor' 
                         and s.editorID = '516' and s.scoreSubmit = '1') = 1")
            ->get();
```